# How to include dollar signs?

Tags: c++

For a project I have to write an application that calculates the price of gas. The code works great, but I noticed something that will probably get points deducted. My total price doesn't include a dollar sign. I am stuck on where to add them and how. Below is my code. Please help!

```
// FinalProject1.cpp : This file contains the 'main' function. Program execution begins and ends there.
//

#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

const double PRICE_OF_REGULAR = 1.67;
const double PRICE_OF_SPECIAL = 1.87;
const double PRICE_OF_SUPER = 1.99;
int main()
{
    cout << "Gas Pump Calculator!" << endl;

    double numberOfGallons;

    cout << "Please enter number of gallons needed: ";
    cin >> numberOfGallons;
    cout << endl;

    cout << "1. Regular" << endl;
    cout << "2. Special" << endl;
    cout << "3. Super+" << endl;
    cout << endl;

    int choice;
    cin >> choice;

    switch (choice)
    {
    case 1:
        cout << endl;
        cout << "You chose regular. The total price of gas is: " << (numberOfGallons * PRICE_OF_REGULAR);
        cout << endl;
        break;
    case 2:
        cout << endl;
        cout << "You chose special. The total price of gas is: " << (numberOfGallons * PRICE_OF_SPECIAL);
        cout << endl;
        break;
    case 3:
        cout << endl;
        cout << "You chose super+. The total price of gas is: " << (numberOfGallons * PRICE_OF_SUPER);
        cout << endl;
        break;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Same place and same way as the other strings your code prints.

Comment: Maybe the OP thought the dollar sign could somehow be added to the `double` variable not knowing that this is impossible.

Answer (score 2):

Just print a dollar sign after the number:

```
cout << "You chose regular. The total price of gas is: " 
     << (numberOfGallons * PRICE_OF_REGULAR) << "$";
                                               //^  add dollar sign
```

Or before the number, depending on how you want to print it out.

```
cout << "You chose regular. The total price of gas is: $" 
     << (numberOfGallons * PRICE_OF_REGULAR);        //^  add dollar sign
```

Comment: @MeghanD Consider accepting the answer, if it solves your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Just add it before your value:

```
cout << "You chose regular. The total price of gas is: $" 
<< (numberOfGallons * PRICE_OF_REGULAR);
```